# Copy folders paths and folders as different inputs powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying a script which should copy the folders where the source and destination are in one input file and the folder names in another input file.

The below script is working which does the job for one source, one destination and multiple folders at a time.

```
$folders = Get-Content -Path D:\input.txt
$Source = Read-host "Enter the Source Path"
$Destination = Read-host "Enter the Destination Path"
foreach ($folder in $folders)
{
Copy-item  -Path $Source\$folder  -Destination $destination\$folder -Recurse -Verbose
}
```

Likewise, I need to copy the folders by inputting multiple source and destination and also multiple folders.

csv sample:
[image]

Text sample:
[image]

Below is the script which I tried but it didnt worked

```
$folders = Get-Content -Path D:\input.txt
$fileName = 'D:\input.csv'
Import-Csv -Path $fileName -UseCulture -PipelineVariable row |
ForEach-Object -Process {
$source = $row.source
$destination = $row.destination
$path1 = Join-path $source $folders
$path2 = Join-Path $destination $folders
copy-item  -Path $path1  -Destination $path2 -Recurse -Verbose
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Where is your `$folder` variable coming from? and what are you trying to do? I'm just no understanding what you're saying

Comment: @AbrahamZinala- My bad...I edited now...My requirement is how to pass two inputs to copy the folders?